# addSubView after dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to add a UIImageView to my ViewController after I dismiss a modal view controller.
But for some reason `[self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];` isn't adding the UIImageView to the display, or at least it's not visible. The example code that I'm calling in the modal view controller is below.

```
/* Modal View Controller */
- (IBAction)hideModal:(id)sender {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
    TestViewController *gv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testView"];
    [gv view];
    [gv addLogo];
   }];
}
/* TestViewController */
-(void)addLogo {
    [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion block was not the same as the initial view controller being displayed. 

 When trying to reference the view controller being displayed under the modal view controller call the below code:

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    gv = (TestViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    [gv displayLogo];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method call from completion block

```
/* Modal View Controller */
- (IBAction)hideModal:(id)sender {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    TestViewController *gv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testView"];
    [gv view];
    [gv addLogo];

}
/* TestViewController */
-(void)addLogo {

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];

    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImageView];
    myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);

    if(myImage)
     {
       [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
       [self.view bringSubViewToFront:myImageView];
     }
    else
     {
       NSLog(@"no image found");
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. I'm very new to objective-c.

Comment: I added that and the image was found, but still no result.

Comment: Also, it has to be [self.view addSubview:myImage];

Comment: could u please send the sample code to ramshadram90@gmail.com ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26575/discussion-between-storm-shadows-and-ramshad)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[self addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"] autorelease]];
```

The other way to do it, is to call addSubview method from viewDidAppear in your TestViewController

Comment: It already had [self.view-- it was a mistake I forgot to add. Also, autorelease doesn't work on iOS 6. It was deprecated.

Comment: autorelease doesn't deprecated in ios6, it rather doesn't work in ARC

Comment: I'll try the viewDidAppear

Comment: Also, make sure, that instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier return you valid instance of TestViewController

Comment: It is returning the right one, but how can I be sure that it's the current view controller that is displaying behind the modal control?

Comment: Add breakpoint in completion block below instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier line, add another breakpoint in viewDidAppear method of TestViewController. Print description of gv in first breakpoint, and description of self in second breakpoint. If memory addresses are equals, view controllers are the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26577/discussion-between-storm-shadows-and-daniil-rumyantsev)